# Jquery and Javascript multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I need to perform different actions for varying divs. I have the following code:

```
$("#pending-cancel-1, #pending-cancel-2").click(function(){

  Do something 1...

});

$("#pending-done-success").click(function(){

  Do something 2...

});
```

Would it be possible to write something like:

```
$("#pending-cancel-1, #pending-cancel-2, #pending-done-success").click(function(){

  ...
  if("#pending-cancel-1, #pending-cancel-2")
      Do something 1...
  else if("#pending-done-success")
      Do something 2...
  else:
      Do something 3...


});
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if (this.id == 'pending-cancel-1')`

Comment: Those are 2 different handlers, combining both makes the code unmanageable and is not a good practice. Really there is no benefit in doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use

```
if ($(this).is("#pending-cancel-1, #pending-cancel-2")) {
```

but it doesn't look very useful here. You don't usually bind an event handler to different elements just to have the behavior change inside depending on the element.

I guess you do this because part of the behavior is shared but even there, I'd rather have different event handlers calling a common function without having to test a selector in the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you merge the 2 functions in the first place, if you would just put a condition in it to separate them?

It seems like a bad design strategy.

Comment: I agree. But this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @undefined I guess sometimes it is best to point out, that the poster should take a different approach because there is a conceptual flaw in the question; and that is the best answer.
Also, the "real" answers have already been posted by other users, I wouldn't like to repeat them.

Comment: I know what you mean, but in that case a comment should be posted, in the comment section of the question. I did upvote the _answer_, but to me it's not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @undefined Well I am quite new to the site as a contributor, my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$("#pending-done-success,#pending-cancel-1, #pending-cancel-2").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  switch(id){
    case 'pending-done-success':
      /* Do something */
      break;
    case 'pending-cancel-1':
      /* Do something */
      break;
    case 'pending-cancel-2':
      /* Do something else */
      break;
  }

});
```

It could be way much cleaner, but; easly, just by adding a common class to them (but Do keep the id), something like this:

```
$(".pending").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  switch(id){
    case 'pending-done-success':
      /* Do something */
      break;
    case 'pending-cancel-1':
      /* Do something */
      break;
    case 'pending-cancel-2':
      /* Do something */
      break;
  }

});
```

Or just like in your example, it would be:

```
$(".pending").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  switch(id){
    case 'pending-done-success':
      /* Do something */
      break;
    case 'pending-cancel-1':
    case 'pending-cancel-2':
      /* Do something */
      break;
  }

});
```

Comment: The id won't contain the # symbol.

Comment: True, I just copied and pasted, that's why its allways easier with a jsfiddle/like thanks for pointing out